# Emacs ignore my .emacs?

Tags: init-file

I set part settings of my EMACS with **cusomize**, and part with manually editing **.emacs**-file in my home directory. Not all settings from my **.emacs** applyed at EMACS startup.

For example, not working **web-beautify** before save, not enable **js2-highlight-unused-variables** on js2-mode and more. But if I select these lines and call command `eval-region`, she begin works!

Also someone settings from **.emacs** works on startup.

What I do wrong?

EMACS version: 24.5.1, builded from source

EMACS repos: ELPA, GNU, ORG

OS version: Ubuntu 14.04 x64

Link to my .emacs: http://pastebin.com/NJup9cDP

Comment: Doesn't Emacs report any errors on start-up? You could also log the .emacs evaluation progress in the `*Messages*` buffer by using `(message "this and this stage reached")` for example. Similarly, you could log hook execution by placing message calls in relevant functions.

Comment: Can the **desktop** mode disable my settings?

Comment: Do you mean `desktop-save-mode`? If so, it's very unlikely, but you can try to figure it out by either starting Emacs with `--no-desktop` option or by removing everything that was saved in the desktop file by calling `M-x desktop-clear` and restarting Emacs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `js2-highlight-unused-variables` is a function used by `js2-highlight-unused-variables-mode`, which is a minor mode:  https://github.com/mooz/js2-mode/blob/master/js2-mode.el

In general, minor modes are turned on as follows:

```
(js2-highlight-unused-variables-mode 1)
```

And, they are turned off as follows:

```
(js2-highlight-unused-variables-mode -1)
```

The original poster has created a function that looks like this:

```
(defun turn-on-highlight-unused-vars-on-js2-mode()(js2-highlight-unused-variables))
```

Instead, the original poster could try the following:

```
(defun turn-on-highlight-unused-vars-on-js2-mode ()
  (js2-highlight-unused-variables-mode 1))
```

---

With respect to `web-beautify`, the original poster will need to carefully compare his/her own code to the instructions on the homepage for the github repository -- https://github.com/yasuyk/web-beautify.  If those instructions do not appear to work, then the original poster may wish to reduce his/her `.emacs` file to the absolute minimal installation needed for `web-beautify` and see if it works as expected.  If `web-beautify` works as expected with a minimal `.emacs` installation, then the original poster can start enabling the other settings little by little until the culprit is located.

The instructions state in relevant part:

*If you want to automatically format before saving a file, add the following hook to your emacs configuration:*

```
(eval-after-load 'js2-mode
  '(add-hook 'js2-mode-hook
             (lambda ()
               (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'web-beautify-js-buffer t t))))

;; Or if you're using 'js-mode' (a.k.a 'javascript-mode')
(eval-after-load 'js
  '(add-hook 'js-mode-hook
             (lambda ()
               (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'web-beautify-js-buffer t t))))

(eval-after-load 'json-mode
  '(add-hook 'json-mode-hook
             (lambda ()
               (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'web-beautify-js-buffer t t))))

(eval-after-load 'sgml-mode
  '(add-hook 'html-mode-hook
             (lambda ()
               (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'web-beautify-html-buffer t t))))

(eval-after-load 'css-mode
  '(add-hook 'css-mode-hook
             (lambda ()
               (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'web-beautify-css-buffer t t))))
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed response! Disabling line with `(ergoemacs-mode 1) resolve my problem.